# How to fix runtime error in online editor?

Tags: python

every time i upload my code in online editor i get runtime error since i can run it without any problem offline ( i mean in my vs code) i think it's for taking input, please help me here is my code

```
 mylist=[]
n=int(input())
x=int(input())
k=int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
    a=input()
    mylist.append(a)
bb=x+k
bc=bb%n
print(mylist[bc-1])
```

i get this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/3ea91305ad98bd23bfc532efbb96d2d8.py", line 3, in <module>
    x=int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: It makes sense that you cannot use `input()` in an online editor. Which editor are you using, by the way?

Comment: I dont get an error when running your code, Maybe add hints to your inputs so you know what you are inputing and when.

Comment: This is not just an online editor ,that is online challenge and i wrote this code and answers which i get are totally right but when i upload the same code for judging i get runtime error and my code cannot be compiled

Comment: Usually on online challenges, you should not include the explicit `input()`. Just assume that the variables `n`, `x` and `k` exist. Would that work for you?

Comment: Actually if i don't take input , then how will i use those variable?

Comment: Every time it shows runtime error but question says you have to take input

Comment: @aaossa Can you elaborate on that?